# Setting status code in Sinatra's custom error block

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, http-status-code-301

I have a custom error message for 400 status code:

```
get '/do' do
  raise ParamXMissingError unless params['x']
end

error ParamXMissingError do
  haml :custom_error_page
end
```

I want ParamXMissingError to be 400, but when I run the above code, and check through Firefox Network tools, it seems Sinatra is actually returning 500, not 400. How do I make it display the `custom_error_page.haml` and return 400?

Preferably, it'd be nice to have the status code and the page handled from inside the error block, not something that I would sprinkle around when raising `ParamXMissingError`. For example, this would be repetitive and not a good solution:`halt 400, haml(:custom_error_page)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doh. All I need is to set `status 400`:

```
error ParamXMissingError do
  status 400
  haml :custom_error_page
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when doing an ajax request, I still get 200s :(. Of course I am doing this in a normal `post` action though.